# Is it possible to Invoke query method in EntityListener callback methods?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a question is it possible to invoke Query or EntityManager method in EntityListener callback methods, or is there any other solution similar to EntityListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityListeners are classes whose methods gets called by JPA when the condition are satisfied. Thes classes are instantiated when required and there's no way to pass any value to the constructor.

The only way to do this is getting the EntityManager from an external class in the method you need to use it. Search HibernateUtils to get an example of this External Class.

Here you are as well a complete example of that: https://gist.github.com/yusufcakmak/215ede715bab0e1d6489

Comment: Thanks for answer i will try to create EntityManager from external class.